# What is the ruling on selling dogs?

Tags: halacha, animals, transactions

If I understand correctly as long as the breed of dog isn’t considered vicious then owning it would be okay but not ideal,
But would one be allowed to sell a dog/puppy and benefit from its sale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues with selling dogs.

1. The proceeds from the sale of a dog may not be used to buy sacrifices. As it says in [Devarim 23:19](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.23.19?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he):

> לֹא־תָבִיא אֶתְנַן זוֹנָה **וּמְחִיר כֶּלֶב** בֵּית יְהוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ לְכָל־נֶדֶר כִּי תוֹעֲבַת יְהוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ גַּם־שְׁנֵיהֶם׃

> You shall not bring the fee of a whore nor **the pay of a dog** into the house of the LORD your Gcd in fulfillment of any vow, for both are abhorrent to the LORD your Gcd.

Selling a puppy is no different to selling any other size dog.

2. One may not own a dangerous dog, as discussed in the Talmud (e.g. [Bava Kama 46a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Kamma.46a.5?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en)) unless one ensures it will not endanger or scare people.

One could argue that a puppy is not dangerous and most people are not scared of puppies, so it shouldn't be a problem to buy one, hence permissible to sell one.

The fact that eventually it will grow into a full-sized dog shouldn't affect the sale, and one can assume that the buyer will ensure that it won't endanger or scare people.

[See here (Hebrew)](https://olamot.net/shiur/%D7%92%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94) for a list of halachic ruling concerning dogs, puppies and selling them.

That said, if the puppy is being bought for *recreational* purposes, it's not ideal, whereas if it's being sold for *security*-related issues, it seems to be perfectly ok.

Comment: https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%91%D7%97_%D7%93_%D7%99%D7%93

Comment: Proceeds from the sale of a dog are allowed for buying korbonos, only exchanging a dog for a korbon is not allowed. [Rambam](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Things_Forbidden_on_the_Altar.4.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Comment: @mordechai that's the link I posted